# How to click through a Selenium WebElement list?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to expand some collapsible content by taking all the elements that need to be expanded, and then clicking on them. Then once they're open, scrape the data shown. So far I'm grabbing a list of elements by their xpath, with this:

```
clicks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'collapsableContent') and contains(@class, 'empty')]")
```

and I've tried iterating with a simple for loop:

```
for item in clicks:
    item.click()
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on where to look?

The specific page I'm trying to get this from is: https://sports.betway.com/en/sports/sct/esports/cs-go

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, does the `clicks` contain valid list of 4 expandable divs? Why you think `.click()` is not working?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you are expecting by clicking on the`empty` div?

Comment: @Xarvalus so it seems to be grabbing them correctly. The error I'm getting is:

    line 80, in click
        self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

Comment: @supputuri thanks! So the empty class seems to denote when the element is collapsed, and it is removed from that div's class when it's expanded. So I was expecting that when they are clicked, they will expand to reveal the elements inside. After which, the scrape will be able to get all these new elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you should use to open all the divs which have the collapsed empty class.

```
# click on close button in cookies policy (as this is the element which will overlap the element clicks)    
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".messageBoxCloseButton.icon-cross").click()
# get all the divs (collapsed divs)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='collapsableContent empty']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='collapsableHeader']")
# click on each of those links
for link in links:
    link.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    link.click()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion. Tried this out, seems to get me a bit further than I was able to which is good. I'm now having a problem where I'm getting the following error:
`File "arb.py", line 112, in <module>
link.click()
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click   self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)`

Seems like it's getting stuck on itself?

Comment: Have you tried the javascript click option `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",link)`.

Comment: Just to update. Your code now works great. Don't know what was causing it to get stuck. Just to be sure I added    time.sleep(0.5) in the loop, just to allow it to iterate a bit slower. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool.If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button in my answer. Feel free to up vote.